# Why are my buildings and zones completely disappearing in Cities Skylines?

Tags: technical-issues, cities-skylines

I am completely new to this and have no idea of gaming lingo. I'm learning by watching 'You tube' and reading blogs, so if you are nice enough to answer my question please be kind. I'm also old.

I have built a really nice city in Cities Skylines and all is going really well, everyone is happy, no problems with traffic or pollution, water, electricity etc. etc.

So why are my buildings and coloured zones completely disappearing in front of my eyes? This is driving me crazy as I will never be able to build a decent city if it keeps disappearing. Because the zoning disappears the electricity fails to connect the buildings, so I go back to put in the zones again and they disappear as fast as I put them back!

There is an orange circular symbol with a line through it which pops up just before I lose everything. I have tried to find out what this is and why, with no luck. I am also only adding more zones when the gauge says so. Is there something wrong with my programme? I would really appreciate any help with this as I have checked all through the internet and no one else has written about this problem before .

Comment: Does your building disappear yet the color under the building stay the same? ie. Does your "zone" still exist? The only time I know of that zones themselves are removed is when you delete or modify a road. Have you touched the road next to the zone at all?

Comment: no the zones disappear as well , it goes back to grass ! and I haven't touched the road at all , it just happens all on its own and it happens a lot !!! I lose whole areas completely.

Comment: I have no idea on this one. If you have Steam, you may want to look for the discussion forums for Cities: Skylines and make a post about it. Other users may have experienced the same problem. You can also make a post on the Cities Skylines forum itself.

Comment: When a symbol is present, click on the building it is on and hover over it in the building's info screen to get the description of the status icon. It may tell you more.

Comment: Thank you both, I will have another go on Steam,  I have found nothing as yet...............with regards to the orange circle symbol ...it is there only for seconds before everything disappears, there is not enough time to click on it ....I have tried, it's like trying to catch a rat down a drain pipe. !!!!!! Also I have tried finding the symbols meaning  on anything relating to cities skylines and cannot find any answers there either !  Really appreciate your comments, thank you.

Comment: @Dee - Where does the circle appear - to be honest I have never seen anything like this in all of my hours of game play.

Comment: You could try to check your local files for errors via steam, honestly I dont expect it to fix the problem but it's worth a try, isn't it?

Comment: If you hit your PrintScreen key quickly when you see that symbol, you should be able to get a screen shot of it that you could then include in your question.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to an issue with assets being renamed when updated:

http://community.simtropolis.com/forums/topic/69058-massive-population-drop-after-update

> themes will become 'corrupted' in case of renamed updated assets (not
>   corrupted as in broken, but corrupted as in missing all assets that
>   were renamed).

The solution seems to be unsubscribing/resubscribing - although, it seems that you will still have a population drop but the buildings will regrow.